# Jquery click on DIV in IE only fires on text and not anywhere in DIV...?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click

I have a DIV:

```
 <div id="leftBoxTools" class="toolboxHeaders" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 100%">
                    TOOLS</div>
```

that I want to fire a click event when someone clicks anywhere on it so I can make a sort of collapsible toolbox :

```
 $(".toolboxHeaders").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

## Works fine in ff and chrome but in ie9 it only works if you click on the actual text and not anywhere in the div... any ideas?

UPDATE:
Just to clarify a bit, this is all happening in a JQ UI Dialog box.  Not sure if that could be causing a problem.  I have looked at the JSFiddle's from this post and they all work fine in IE9.  Yet, I still cannot get my particular issue to work.

I am also doing all this in an old aspx application that is using frames AND master pages (guh)... so it's really hard to tell what is causing this.

I HAVE changed the doctype to HTML5 but still can't get it to fire a click on anything but the text.

Comment: Read: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: It may be a problem in css. I mean with the `width` of div. Try with a `width:500px` in place of `width:100%`

Comment: Could be a stacking context issue caused by transparency in a div?
http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the **`DOCTYPE`** you are using.

I did a live test, http://jsfiddle.net/kYcD9/ , and it is working fine in IE9.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, turned out that in my css file i had:

`body { z-index: -1}`

After removing that everything worked fine.  That is why these were working in the jsfiddle, and not on mine.

Answer (score 1):

it works fine in IE9 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PBNcq/1/))

Here is the code:

```
 <div id="leftBoxTools" class="toolboxHeaders" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 100%; height:60px; background-color:red;">
                TOOLS

</div>
<div>another </div>
```

The JS:

```
$(".toolboxHeaders").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

The `div` with content "another" will slide up/down upon clicking anywhere in the red area.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason why I was having this issue was different, but for me what solved it was giving the div the background property:

```
.myactivediv {
    ...
    background: #E8E6EE;
    ...
}
```

Comment: In that case, it is probably to do with 'stacking context', philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index